# Execute query within query (PostgresAdmin III)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a very long cleaning procedure with 1000s of "replaces".
I saved this in a separate file.
All other processes are defined in another query. 
I would like to execute the cleaning file from the main query.
Is this possible and how to do that?

Example:
Main query file

```
create table a as
select * from b;
--a lot of other stuff--

execute cleaning query here!! -- I want to execute the cleaning query within my main query 
-- cleaning query looks as follows (don't want to paste this into main query):
create table a_ as 
select *, replace(replace(replace(...(a1
, 'WORD1', '')
, 'WORD2', '')
, 'WORD3', '')
... from a ;
-- end of cleaning query
--again a lot of stuff --
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using a trigger. [PostgreSqlDocumentation: trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

A trigger allows you to call functions (query); you can also declare it *for each row* so you can write a query which refers to only one generic row, than the trigger will apply it to every row of the table (you can also ask for a condition to be fulfilled)